# What's the meaning of $C$-embedded?

Tags: general-topology, definition

What's the meaning of $C$-embedded? It is a topological notion. Thanks ahead.

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/CEmbedded.html ?

Comment: thanks for the link. it is useful for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A set $A \subset X$ ($X$ is a topological space) is $C$-embedded in $X$ iff every real-valued continuous function $f$ defined on $A$ has a continuous extension $g$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (so $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$).

A related notion of $C^{\ast}$-embedded exist where continuous real-valued functions are (in both cases) replaced by **bounded** real-valued continuous functions.

The Tietze theorem basically says that a closed subset $A$ of a normal space $X$ is $C$ and $C^{\ast}$-embedded in it.