# Are pseudonormal pseudocompacts all weakly countably compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

[All normal pseudocompacts are weakly countably compact](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000110) (that is, infinite subsets cannot be closed and discrete).

Can "normal" be weakened to "pseudonormal"? A space is pseudonormal provided for every *countable* closed set $H$ and open $U\supseteq H$, there is an open set $V$ with $H\subseteq V\subseteq cl(V)\subseteq U$.

Comment: This is true for Tychonoff spaces by exercise 3L.5 of Gillman and Jerison. I'd include a proof but I can't think well today. I can see there being a strongly connected space which doesn't satisfy this property. Is Hewitt corkscrew pseudonormal?

Comment: Well, I don't think you need more than complete regularity (+ pseudonormal) for this result though (i.e. the assumption of $T_1$ is not needed)

Comment: Since normal doesn't imply completely regular without T1, it would be very interesting if pseudonormal required completely regular to follow through.

Comment: As I show below, we have a property that's weaker than both completely regular and normal, but from which the proposition still follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that $X$ is *completely regular for closed points* if for any closed $x\in X$ and disjoint closed $F\subseteq X$ there is a continuous function $f:X\to [0, 1]$ such that $f(x) = 0$ and $f\equiv 1$ on $F$.

Say that $X$ is *regular for closed points* if for any closed $x\in X$ and disjoint closed $F\subseteq X$ there are disjoint open $U, V$ such that $x\in U$ and $F\subseteq V$.

Note that both pseudonormal and completely regular for closed points imply regular for closed points.

Also both normal and completely regular implies completely regular for closed points.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be regular for closed points and $D\subseteq X$ be countable closed and discrete. Then there are disjoint open $U_x, x\in D$ with $x\in U_x$.

*Proof:* Proceed by induction. $\square$

**Proposition.** Suppose that $X$ is pseudonormal, completely regular for closed points, and $D\subseteq X$ is a closed countably infinite discrete set. Then $D$ is [$C$-embedded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189922/whats-the-meaning-of-c-embedded) in $X$.

*Proof:*

Let $D = \{x_1, x_2, ...\}$. For each $n$ take open $U_n$ with $x_n\in  U_n$ and all $U_n$ disjoint. Since $X$ is pseudonormal, we can take open $U$ such that $D\subseteq U\subseteq \overline{U}\subseteq \bigcup_n U_n$. Let $g:D\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $f_n:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $f_n(x_n) = g(x_n)$ and $f_n\equiv 0$ for $(U_n\cap U)^c$. Let $f\equiv f_n$ on $U_n$ and $f\equiv 0$ on $U^c$, then $f$ is well-defined. Moreover, $f
\restriction_{U_n}$ and $f\restriction_{\overline{U}^c}$ are continuous. From gluing lemma, $f$ is continuous. $\square$

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a pseudocompact, pseudonormal and completely regular for closed points. Then $X$ is weakly countably compact.

*Proof:*

If $X$ is not weakly completely compact, let $D\subseteq X$ be closed countably infinite and discrete. From the lemma, $D$ is $C$-embedded in $X$. But by picking an unbounded function on $D$ and extending it to $X$, this contradicts pseudocompactness. $\square$

**Corollary.** Let $X$ be either a completely regular pseudonormal space, or a normal space. If $X$ is pseudocompact, then $X$ is weakly countably compact.